# Polymorphic functors in std::for_each

Tags: c++, stl, polymorphism

I'm trying to use stl algorithm for_each without proliferating templates throughout my code. std::for_each wants to instantiate MyFunctor class by value, but it can't since its abstract. I've created a functor adapter class which passes a pointer around and then derefernces it when appropriate.

My Question:

Does the STL or Boost already have such an adapter class? I don't want to have to reinvent the wheel!

```
 struct MyFunctor  {
     virtual ~MyFunctor() {}
     virtual void operator()(int a) = 0; 
 }

 namespace {
     template<typename FunctorType, typename OperandType> struct
 FunctorAdapter
     {
         FunctorAdapter(FunctorType* functor) : mFunctor(functor) {}
         void operator()(OperandType& subject)
         {
             (*mFunctor)(subject);
         }

         FunctorType* mFunctor;
     }; }

 void applyToAll(MyFunctor &f) {
     FunctorHelper<MyFunctor, int> tmp(&f);
     std::for_each(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), tmp); }
```

Cheers,

Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tr1::ref may help you here --- it's meant to be a reference wrapper so that you can pass normal objects by reference to bind or function objects (even abstract ones) by reference to standard algorithms.

```
// requires TR1 support from your compiler / standard library implementation
#include <functional>

void applyToAll(MyFunctor &f) {
    std::for_each(
        myvector.begin(), 
        myvector.end(), 
        std::tr1::ref(f) 
    ); 
}
```

However, NOTE that compilers without decltype support *MAY* reject passing a reference to an abstract type... so this code may not compile until you get C++0x support.

Comment: It looks like I have implemented, in FunctorAdapter, something very similar to reference_wrapper which tr1::ref returns.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the function adapters (and their shims) from `functional`.

```
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
for_each( vec.begin(), vec.end(), :mem_fun_ptr( &MyClass::f ) );
```

If your container contains pointers-to-objects, use `mem_fun_ptr`, else use `mem_fun`.  Next to these, there are wrappers for member functions that take 1 argument: `mem_fun1_ptr` and `mem_fun1`.

@Evan: indeed, you could call the member function with the same argument for each object.  The first argument of the `mem_fun1` wrappers is the `this` pointer, the second is the member  function argument:

```
for_each( vec.begin(), vec.end(), bind2nd( mem_fun_ptr( &MyClass::f ), 1 ) );
```

With more arguments, it becomes more readable to create a loop yourself, or create a custom functor that has const member variables representing the arguments.

Comment: good answer, I'm unclear from his example, but if the vector contains ints, doesn't he also need to bind1st a "this pointer" to that mem_fun?

Comment: No, because the this pointer will be passed as the argument by for_each. Member function pointers will handle the virtual lookup.

Comment: Cant understand why this has got more votes than the correct answer; it doesn't work with functor objects as requested.

Answer (score 0):

What about forgetting all the wrapping of the functor pointer, and instead use 
`bind(functor_pointer,mem_fun1(&MyFunctor::operator());`

 as the functor?  that way, you don't have to worry about managing the copy in any way shape or form.

Answer (score 0):

why not use BOOST_FOREACH?

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/foreach.html

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could benefit from [Boost::Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/function.html).

If I remember correctly it's a header only library too, so it's easy to get it going with it.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @xtofl's answer, since the array contains int's and not "this" pointers, I think the correct incantation is

```
class MyClass
{
  virtual void process(int number) = 0;
};
MyClass *instance = ...;

for_each( vec.begin(), vec.end(), binder1st(instance, mem_fun_ptr(&MyClass::process) );
```

The only difference versus @xtofl's code is binder1st rather than binder2nd. binder2nd allows you to pass teh same number to various "this" pointers. binder1st allows you to pass various numbers to one "this" pointer.